# What is a word that means to condescend in a positive way, such as the way an adult would speak simply to a young child so they could understand

Tags: meaning

What is a word that means to condescend in a positive way, such as the way an adult would speak simply to a young child so they could understand?  I mean with kindness and without an air of superiority.  Thanks for any suggestions. :)

Comment: like 'patronize' but not so negative?

Comment: Condescension without smugness would simply be *explanation*, wouldn't it?

Comment: Similar question to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146148/is-there-a-saying-in-english-that-basically-means-adapting-to-your-target-audie but not sure if it's a duplicate

Comment: @Mitch  Thanks for responding. :)  I think "condescend" used to have a more positive connotation long, long ago? I wish it still did.  :)  I need a word for a poem I'm writing.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dan Bron Thanks for responding. :)  I think "condescend" used to have a more positive connotation long, long ago? I wish it still did.  :)  I need a word for a poem I'm writing.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Hatchet Yes!  I think that might do it!  The word, "syncatabasis".  Thanks so much!  However, given that the regular online dictionaries don't seem to know it, maybe it's too archaic to be useful?  Hmmm...  Thanks!

Comment: They’re not exactly the same, but maybe “relate to” or “connect with”? You’re right that condescend used to be more positive, like an aristocrat treating a working-class person as an equal.

Answer (score 5):

You could call that "speaking on someone's level".

**She spoke to the kindergartners on their level.**

Comment: Yes - *spoke on same level with sympathy to the children's understanding.* *Condescending* is definitely not a word to use - it expresses the speakers low regard for the listener.

Comment: Tim Romano and @WS2  Thanks for responding. :)  I think "condescend" used to have a more positive connotation long, long ago? I wish it still did.  :)  I'd like  to have one word rather than a phrase, but I'll work with it somehow.  :)  (Writing a poem).  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

How about the word **vouchsafe**?

You can use it in place of *condescend* as instantiated by: *He **vouchsafed** an explanation to the conundrum*

[vouchsafe](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vouchsafing)

Answer (score -2):

The adjective **debonair** may fit.

> *Definition*: urban, gracious and charming in a cheerful, carefree, light-hearted way ; having a good disposition.
>
> *Example*: My grandfather is the most debonair person you’ll ever meet.
> He is a very warm-hearted, genial gentleman who showed nothing but kindness to us.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, but I don't think "debonair" quite fits my purpose.  I really do appreciate your taking the time to try, though.  :)